# How to uninstall Ruby from /usr/local?

Tags: ruby, installation, uninstallation

Everything was working fine , until we decided to upgrade ruby to 1.8.7 from 1.8.6, and thats when all hell broke loose. When we compiled Ruby 1.8.7 from source it got installed into /usr/local/bin and Ruby 1.8.6 stayed in /usr/bin. 
Currently, we've uninstalled ruby 1.8.6 and by some stroke we deleted the ruby 1.8.7 files from /usr/local.

when we try "which ruby" it points to /usr/local.
If anybody could help us out what we need to do get back on track , we would be very grateful.and also any idea how we can uninstall ruby from /usr/local. 
we tried yum remove ruby , which removed ruby from /usr/bin.Thanks and Cheers !

Comment: For Mac OS Users, > brew uninstall ruby should work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not a good idea to uninstall 1.8.6 if it's in `/usr/bin`. That is owned by the OS and is expected to be there.

If you put `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH before `/usr/bin` then things you have installed in `/usr/local/bin` will be found before any with the same name in `/usr/bin`, effectively overwriting or updating them, without actually doing so. You can still reach them by explicitly using `/usr/bin` in your #! interpreter invocation line at the top of your code.

@Anurag recommended using RVM, which I'll second. I use it to manage 1.8.7 and 1.9.1 in addition to the OS's 1.8.6.

Answer (score 23):

Edit: As suggested in comments. This solution is for Linux OS. That too if you have installed ruby manually from package-manager.

If you want to have multiple ruby versions, better to have [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install). In that case you don't need to remove ruby older version.

Still if want to remove then follow the steps below:

First you should find where Ruby is:

```
whereis ruby
```

will list all the places where it exists on your system, then you can remove all them explicitly. Or you can use something like this:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gem
rm -f /usr/bin/gem
```

Comment: It is *REALLY* important to find out what OS and version this is running on, before suggesting someone remove Ruby from `/usr`. Apple includes Ruby in Snow Leopard and has code calling it from apps. Deleting those will break the apps silently. If it is a Linux system, and Ruby was installed via a package-manager, then that should be used to remove the files. And, in either case, using something like RVM can negate the need to delete a pre-installed Ruby at all.

Comment: Sadness ensues if someone copy/pastes that chunk of rm commands.  Don't copy/paste without reading kids.

Comment: While removing ruby don't forget to remove also other ruby-related stuff like `erb`, `gem`, `irb`, `rake`, `rdoc`, `ri`, `testrb` (for me in `/usr/local/bin`).

Answer (score 5):

Create a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) at /usr/bin named 'ruby' and point it to the latest installed ruby.

You can use something like `ln -s /usr/bin/ruby /to/the/installed/ruby/binary`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you mean /etc/bin/ruby or /usr/bin/ruby? Also, there are additional ruby-related names that need to be linked such as irb, rdoc, etc.

Comment: Greg,my bad... You pointed it correctly, it's /usr/bin/ruby, just like the first line. I'll correct it. 

Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm going to suggest NOT doing any links in `/usr/bin` to other versions of Ruby if the OS installed Ruby in `/usr/bin` by default. On Apple's Snow Leopard, Apple is now installing code that uses Ruby 1.8.7 which is preinstalled in `/usr/bin`. Messing with that could cause subtle bugs/failures down the road in that app or any that come along later. Any more I think it's better to use RVM to manage sandboxed Rubies or install into `/usr/local/bin` or maybe somewhere under `/opt/` and adjust your path; Put it somewhere the system won't assume to look.

Answer (score 2):

If ruby was installed in the following way:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

You can uninstall it in the following way:

Check installed ruby version; lets assume 2.1.2

```
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
bunzip ...
tar xfv ...
cd ruby-2.1.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo checkinstall
  # will build deb or rpm package and try to install it
```

After installation, you can now remove the package and it will remove the directories/files/etc.

```
sudo rpm -e ruby # or dpkg -P ruby (for Debian-like systems)
```

There might be some artifacts left:

```
Removing ruby ...
  warning: while removing ruby, directory '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems' not empty so not removed.
  ...
```

Remove them manually.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo make uninstall` did the trick for me using the Ruby 2.4 tar from the official downloads page.

Answer (score -2):

do this way :

```
sudo apt purge ruby
```