# two versions of ruby installed, how to fix that?

Tags: ruby

I found out that I have two versions of ruby installed on OSX 10.6.2 how can I uninstall the older version and make sure that everything is fine, the path point to the other one?

```
bash-3.2$  /usr/local/bin/ruby -v 
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9.7.0]

bash-3.2$ /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0]


bash-3.2$ $PATH
bash: /usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec: No such file or directory

bash-3.2$ whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Mac OS 10.6 installs Ruby 1.8.7 for its own use. You're free to use it, but understand that Apple put it there for a reason, and modifying or removing it could break the app it's supporting, which you probably won't realize until some point in the future when you've forgotten what you did. Try: `find /usr -name '*.rb'` to see for yourself. As recommended below, use RVM to manage your Ruby installs.

Comment: To install RVM follow the directions on http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ including the "Post Install" section. Also, type `rvm notes` once it is installed and install the dependencies, before installing a Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Ruby in `/usr/bin` is the system-installed version, and should be left in place.

The version you have in `/usr/local/bin` can probably be safely removed. Was it installed using a package manager (ie, MacPorts, Homebrew?). If so, remove it using your package manager.

If you compiled and installed it manually, you can try removing the binaries from `/usr/local/bin`, but you may still have gems and other files lying around (most likely in `/usr/local/lib/ruby`.)

Alternatively, you can leave them in place and manage your Ruby environment through RVM: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: but the system one is older, what if I want to use newer one?

Comment: Well, you can leave them both in place, but you'll have to ensure that you're careful with specifying your paths. This is why I recommend RVM – it handles that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should locate the Ruby you're actively using with `which ruby`, not `whereis ruby`. My `whereis ruby` outputs `/usr/bin/ruby`, but `which ruby` gives `/Users/BinaryMuse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby`, because I manage my Ruby versions with RVM. Since `/usr/local/bin` is first in your PATH, `which ruby` will probably return `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, which appears to be what you want. A quick `ruby -v` can confirm this too.

All that being said, I second the recommendation of using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage version of Ruby and also what RVM calls gemsets, allowing you to have "buckets" of gems that you can use one at a time. It's quite a powerful and extremely useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to uninstall the the older version. ALternatively you can use alias like and save it in the ~/.profile file of your the OSX directory.

alias ruby="<path_to_ruby_version_that_you_want_to_use>"

That should call ruby from the proper directory that you want.

Alternatively you can use symlink like this post suggests here [How to uninstall Ruby from /usr/local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591501/how-to-uninstall-ruby-from-usr-local). Hope it helps!