# Ruby version not same as installed version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version

I am trying to install Ruby on rails on a Mac Mojave:

```
$ brew install ruby
Warning: ruby 2.7.1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.7.1, run `brew reinstall ruby`
```

This shows me that I am running Ruby 2.7.1.

But when I check the version I get:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

This tells me I am using Ruby 2.3.7.

I don't understand.

To run Rails I need >= 2.4.4 apparently:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
.....................
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4.
```

and

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

So until I get ruby version to at least 2.4.4 I can't run rails.

### Update

Install RVM on MAC as follows

```
$ brew install gpg
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled --ruby
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

Got these instructions from:
https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/mac-for-hackers-install-rvm-maintain-ruby-environments-macos-0174401/

But then I install Rails:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-6.0.2.2
Parsing documentation for rails-6.0.2.2
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

and so I tried to crate a Rails project:

```
$ rails new blah
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
$ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

What is going on there? I seem to have successfully installed Rails but cannot create a Rails project.

Comment: Can you tell us the output of `which ruby` ?

Comment: Ok that is added thanks

Comment: What I suspect is the ruby that has been added to your path/bashrc file is the 2.3.7 ruby. And the other installation which is not in path/bashrc file is the up to date 2.7.1 version.

Comment: I would suggest running `brew uninstall ruby` and then installing it again. Also while its being installed pay attention to where it's being installed.

Comment: Once that is done I can walk you through adding the new ruby installation to the `~/bashrc` file

Comment: Ok great thanks, I will do that now

Comment: $ brew uninstall ruby 
done and now 
$brew install ruby 
again?

Comment: I did some digging around and it turns out apple installs ruby in usr/bin/ruby which they use presumably for internal purposes in the OS. Refer to this answer as well to get a better understanding of whats happening https://stackoverflow.com/a/5214030/13206920

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210929/discussion-between-y4glory-and-shane-g).

Comment: After $ which ruby I get 
/usr/bin/ruby so the system version of ruby must still be there

Comment: yes you can try ruby -v

Comment: As you can see in the updated post i can now install rails successfully but can't create a rails project

Comment: Hey has this  been resolved?

Comment: basically rails has not been added to path (I know this seems so redundant), so I recommend running `which rails` and adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc` using `export PATH=<"output of which rails>"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I notice the end of my ~/.bash_profile file has # MacPorts Installer addition on 2019-02-01_at_16:54:10: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from this command `brew install ruby` is not telling you that you're **running** ruby 2.7.1. That just says you already have ruby 2.7.1 installed **for brew**. But you could have other ruby versions installed in other ways. When you do

```
ruby -v
```

`ruby` executable is looked for in paths listed inside your environment variable `PATH`, in order. You can see those paths with

```
echo $PATH
```

So, managing different versions of ruby is hard and version managers exist for this reason. I suggest you to install [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

Comment: Thanks I just want one system wide version of Ruby, I am not trying to manage different versions

Comment: Two ways then: specify the entire path for your ruby executable 2.7.1 or edit your path variable to have that version path before the system one

Comment: I still suggest the version manager because even if you want just one version your system probably already have one you want it or not

Comment: you're welcome. I'm sorry that's not exactly what you expected